# require is not defined in webpack, node environment

Tags: javascript, webpack, server-side-rendering, webpack-4

I'm getting this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Specifically it's failing for `http = require('http')`

One of my dependencies is using that library. I am using Webpack (v4) to bundle my Javascript code.

The relevant bundled code looks like this:

```
/***/ "http":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** external "http" ***!
  \***********************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = require("http")

/***/ }),
```

I am already using a node environment context by adding the following option to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    target: 'node',
}
```

It's a pretty long config file, but that is the relevant part.

I should mention that I am evaluating the bundled code via server-side rendering using a library like [MiniRacer](https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer) (uses V8 Javascript engine). I'm *not* just running `node bundle.js`.

Comment: What version of Node is installed?

Comment: @andrunix using node 12.13.1